# In Textmate, how do I permanently "Add Existing Files.." for a folder?

Tags: textmate

I renamed a folder in Textmate, and then it started disappearing from the drawer and the search index. So I'd "Add Existing Files.." and it would come back, but then disappear again after a while spontaneously. I've reinstalled Textmate, recreated the folder in Finder, renamed the folder back, added a new folder and then renamed it, and nothing has worked so far. Somehow TM knows not to add a folder with that name now.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look into to **Textmate Preferences**. Go to **Advanced** tab, and **Folder References**. Edit the **File Pattern** and/or **Folder Pattern** correspondingly to make sure that the file/folder that you wish to appear is not being ignored.

For more help, you can refer to TextMaate Manual under [2.1.2 Filtering Unwanted Files](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files).